# How to update data in gridview using a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am try to update data in grid view using a stored procedure but I get an error:

> No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox to a known managed provider native type.

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateUser]
    @id int,
    @FirstName nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE tblUsers 
    SET FirstName = @FirstName 
    WHERE id = @id 
END
GO
```

Code

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt16(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
    TextBox FirstName = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox1");

    cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateUser", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName);

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    bindData();
    con.Close();
}
```

Can you suggest me how to solve this error?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="id" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
     OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
    OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"
     OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="id" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblFname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval ("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblLname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblAddress" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("address") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Email") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Phone">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Phone") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Try `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName.Text);'. You are trying to send the Control instead of it's contents.

Comment: till it shows the same error

Comment: Then you are doing the same thing somewhere else. If try your code without `.Text` i get the same error, with it your snippet works fine. Did you rebuild your project?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a `TextBox` variable to your query. If you do this it should work:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing a TextBox object to the AddWithValue method. Since it only recognizes native types it gives the error you are seeing.

You should pass the Textbox.Text value, not the object itself.

Change your code to be like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName.Text);
```

EDIT 1:

Try changing this:

```
TextBox FirstName = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox1");
```

To this:

```
TextBox FirstName = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[GridView1.EditIndex].FindControl("TextBox1");
```

Comment: @LoveAajkal Can you share the code for the GridView, please?